# UIImage.animatedImageNamed returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimage, watchkit

I am trying to load a sequence of images in an animation. I am keeping those images in the assets (spinner1 to spinner42) and so I am using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: WKInterfaceImage!
    override func didAppear() {
        super.didAppear()
        let animatedImage = UIImage.animatedImageNamed("spinner", duration: 10)
        imageView.setImage(animatedImage)
    }
}
```

But I am always returned a nil image. If I set spinner1, I se the image but no animation. What is the proper way to animate an image on WatchKit?

Comment: code updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this Code:** Tested in Swift 3

```
  @IBOutlet var imageView: WKInterfaceImage!
  override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    imageView.setImageNamed("earth") // earth is the image set I'm using for animation.

    // Use this for Default Settings
   // imageView.startAnimating()

    imageView.startAnimatingWithImages(
        in: NSRange(location: 0, length: 40),
        duration: 7,
        repeatCount: 1)
}
```

**Note:** Image set i am using to test this code found from this link http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/watchkit/animation_images.zip you can use this image for testing purpose...

Output:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it was not clear enough that I need to show the animation in WatchKit, and in that framework WKInterfaceImage lacks both animationImages and animationDuration

Comment: i thought. it could work on watchKit framework..let me see.thanks for letting me know...

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I do it:

```
    self.imageProgress.setImageNamed("progress")
    self.imageProgress.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSRange(location:0, length: intPercentageDone), duration: 0.5, repeatCount: 1)
```

I have a bunch of images called "progress1", "progress2" ... up to "progress100"

intPercentageDone is the integer value to animate up to e.g. I want to animate images 1-60 if intPercentageDone is 60

The full code is on GitHub at https://github.com/bravelocation/daysleft/blob/master/daysleft%20WatchKit%20Extension/InterfaceController.swift

Answer (score 0):

As for also the updated answer from joe the correct code I also used is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: WKInterfaceImage!
override func didAppear() {
    super.didAppear()
    imageView.setImageNamed("spinner")
    imageView.startAnimatingWithImages(in:NSRange(location:1, length: 41), duration: 2, repeatCount: 0)
}
```